# Where did my Human Avenger's bonus at-will go in Wizards' Character Builder?

Tags: dnd-4e

I'm building a human avenger in the Character Builder. When I select everything, I only get two at-will powers, though from what I understand I should get three. Is this a bug, or am I missing something about the avenger class?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two options that you can select as a Human

- Heroic Effort power, which at the moment is autoseleted (though you can deselect)
- Bonus At Will power, which is what it sounds like you are intending to use.

[image: character builder screenshot]

The Heroic Effort power was introduced as an option for humans in the Essentials players books. The Bonus At Will power is from the original Players Handbook

Comment: Ah, thanks, totally missed that in the builder.